# How to fix GADDelegateManager didYouNilOutYourDelegate:selector: error

Tags: ios

I am using Admob in my app.

I am getting following error:
    [GADDelegateManager didYouNilOutYourDelegate:selector:] at GADDelegateManager.m:48

I am releasing my Admob Banner object in dealloc.

Can anyone tell what can be the possible fix for this error.

```
-(void)displayAds {     
    self.aBannerView.adUnitID = AdmobPublisherID;  
    [self.aBannerView setDelegate:self];
    [self.aBannerView setRootViewController:roorViewController];

    if (isAdLoaded) {        
        [self.view addSubview:self.aBannerView];
    } else {
        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
        [self.view addSubview:self.aBannerView];
        [self.aBannerView loadRequest:[self createRequest]];        
        isAdLoaded = YES;
    }
}

#pragma mark GADRequest generation

- (GADRequest *)createRequest {
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
    return request;
}

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"Received ad successfully popup");
    if(self.aBannerView !=nil) {
        self.aBannerView.hidden = NO;

    }   
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
    [self.aBannerView removeFromSuperview];
    [self showInhouseAd];
}

 - (void)adViewWillLeaveApplication:(GADBannerView *)bannerView {

}

- (void)dealloc {    
    [aBannerView release];
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Share some code please

Answer (score 1):

The selector name seems rather explanatory to me. Try setting the delegate to nil before releasing the banner view:

```
- (void)dealloc {    
    [aBannerView setDelegate:nil];
    [aBannerView release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error actually says `[GADDelegateManager didYouNilOutYourDelegate:selector:]`. I would actually try

```
- (void)dealloc 
{    
    aBannerView.delegate = nil;
    [aBannerView release];
}
```

That seems like your problem as indicated by the error message.